# sql:server group data by date ignoring time

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a column with type of **datetime**

```
select * from mytable group by dateadded
```

but I want my group by to ignore time value of the datetime and use only date part. then

```
2013-10-05 12:14:15
2013-10-05 19:15:20
```

both would be the same as

```
 2013-10-05 00:00:00
```

and records will be grouped by day. I mean all records that added in one day will be in the same group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from mytable 
group by CONVERT(date, dateadded)
```

Answer (score 0):

juergen's answer works for SQL Server 2008 and above. For SQL Server 2005 and below, use this:

```
select * from mytable
group by DATEDIFF(d, dateadded, '1900-01-01')
```

Or the slightly hackish but perfectly functioning:

```
select * from mytable
group by convert(int, dateadded)
```

Obviously **none** of these examples actually work, because `select *` is incompatible with `group by`. The `select` list needs to have only the expressions from `group by`, or aggregates of other expressions in it.